Error thrown by .z.pd, non unique handles
can someone help with the following error:
2024.06.05D00:02:14.371532071 | serverName | wdb | procname_wdb | ERR | runHooks | Failed to run hook(“.eod.namespace1.functionname[tab1;tab2]”;”.z.pd – expected unique vector of int handles”)
This process is started with -s -2
the .z.pd function is defined like:
.z.pd:{$[.z.K<3.3;
       `u#`int$();
       `u#exec w from .servers.getservers[`proctype;sortworkertypes;()!();1b;0b]]
}

.z.pd[] returns `u`int$()
The above is in one of the colums in a table
time                          query

-------------------------------------------------

2009.08.05D09:25:53.693765248 "function1[params]"

2012.08.18D19:47:01.117332288 "function2[params]"

and I run it as {@[value;x`query;{.log.error[name;"Message"]}]}each table
UPDATE: It seems that removing the -s -2 when starting the process fixes the issue, but I still don't know how I should design my query to work with "-s -2". bear in mind that I want this ran locally, not with peach. There are other areas in the code where it seems like each works fine. Making me think that maybe ... it's the value string that is causing the issue

My understanding is that you can't have peach run locally whenever you're using multi-process (negative s) mode with an empty .z.pd. If you were running worker threads rather than worker processes it would be different - peach would use the threads if configured or would run locally otherwise. But for multi-process mode it specifically needs a list of handles (aka `u#`int$() won't cut it).
Even if you configured the zero handle (local handle) in .z.pd it doesn't like it.
q).z.pd:`u#1#0i
q){x+1}peach 1 2
'0 is not an ipc handle
  [0]  {x+1}peach 1 2
            ^

One way to work around it is to check your .z.pd and use peach/each accordingly:
q).z.pd:`u#`int$()
q){x+1}peach 1 2
'.z.pd - expected unique vector of int handles
  [0]  {x+1}peach 1 2
            ^
q))\
q)$[count .z.pd;peach;each][{x+1};1 2]
2 3

You could even redefine the peach/each functions to perform this check so you don't have to change every peach/each in your code (though modifying the built-in functions is generally frowned upon)

hi. thank you. but this fails on a each. I am not trying to use peach here.
I just want to run a simple each and that's all

ok, but is something inside the functions doing a peach? i.e. is your .eod.namespace1.functionname doing a peach somewhere?

100% not . it's such a simple function . that's why I am puzzled as well :( there is stuff in the code that runs peach but it works fine on all the other servers with no workers started and no .z.pd set

Does this work {@[value;x`query;{.log.error[name;"Message"]}]}each([]query:("1+1";"2+2")) If this works then it implies the issue isn't with each in the local process but with something inside the functions, if not perhaps you have a custom each function?

Also, are you using a version <3.3? I'm testing with 4.0

This {@[value;xquery;{.log.error[name;"Message"]}]}each([]query:("1+1";"2+2"))` works fine.
I am using 4.1
